# Outlook 2010: Color highlight email text with color in inbox for high priority email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, colors, highlighting

In Microsoft Outlook 2010, is it possible to highlight an email to a different color if it's more important?  I notice that when email is flagged in the recipient inbox if the sender marks the email before they send.  However, I just want to be able to set up rules to color highlight them.  How do I do this?

Example:

- highlight email to orange if the domain on the FROM email address is from "@gmail.com"

## EDIT:

Screen shot per my comment:

[image]

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: Nothing so far.  I didn't see color highlighting in the Rules and Alerts dialog in Outlook 2010 (see screen shot).  I was hoping someone had developed a plugin or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done via conditional formatting. To do this use the "View" tab and change the View Settings.

[image]

To make someones name appear in a certain color;

1. Click Add.
2. Enter a name for the rule.
3. Click Font.
4. Under Color, click the color you want.
5. Click OK.
6. Click Condition.
7. In the From box, type the person's name. 
   *Note: The name must exactly match the full name that appears on messages that you receive.*
8. In the Filter, Conditional Formatting, and Advanced View Settings
   dialog boxes, click OK.

For more detailed instructions - [Automatically change incoming message colors and fonts based on sender, subject, or recipients](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/automatically-change-incoming-message-colors-and-fonts-based-on-sender-subject-or-recipients-HA102054868.aspx).